# How to get rid of Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'catalog_category_flat_store_1' doesn't exist?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, error, flat-catalog

> Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'catalog_category_flat_store_1' doesn't exist

I have see some answer for this question but its quick fix after some time I have same issue. But I get this error frequently. We can't say customer always to try again or refresh page. If I refresh page or do re-index I can see table available.

As part of debug I tried to `DROP table` manually and then visit pages but I can't see any error but I found that when table is not exits Magento will disable Flat table option in admin. so here I am not sure when this error occurs and what is the best solution to get rid of this.

If anybody found any solution to get rid of this problem permanently?
For your information I have repair database as well as I replace flat table with fresh Magento table but still no luck I get error again after 2 days.

Comment: what is the `compilation status` of your store?? is it enable or disable?

Comment: Thanks @AsishHira. No compilation is not enable in my store.

Comment: i guess you have some database issues, and reindex will crash or delete this table. you need to find out any mysql errors

Comment: Do you have an extension (poorly build one) that reads values directly from that table?

Comment: @Marius There was module before for dynamic [category](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-dynamiccategory) but Now I have made script and using query i update data for categories by cron and we used magmi for import product from erp system.

Comment: @MagenX We have import process run every 1 hour to import new product from erp system and assign it to category based on attribute value of category and product i have made 2 attribute to make relation for product and categories

Comment: but not direct query to flat table. And Yes Reindexing done every hour after import process

Comment: by any chance you have a stack trace of the error message? Does it say where this comes from? what file?

Comment: @Marius Yes I have seen var/reports  and there is error report showing table doesn't exit and last url was ../xyz.html any category url. sometime i didnt notice but i can see error report some customer inform us for getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running a store with a very small number of products/categories you may want to simply disable the flat tables in `System > Settings > Catalog`.  This can also sometimes be the case for very large catalogs as there is an obvious trade off to flattening the EAV tables. 1) It's less indexing that has to happen. 2) It can sometimes be faster if certain scenarios mentioned above are the case.

How are you normally re-indexing via the CLI? Do you receive any Exception or error messages when running it from the command line? `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall` ?

You should also take a look in `var/log/exception.log` & `var/log/system.log` to see if there is any insight into the indexing failing.  As what may be occurring is when your integration cron runs for Magmi, a reindex could be triggered that is failing, a normal operation for the `*_flat` tables is to drop the table before rebuilding it, it's a temporary table as you mentioned dropping the table manually works briefly. With this in mind, the indexer may start, hit an issue causing the indexer to fail and leaving the `_flat` table missing until a manual reindex happens.  More details on your store's setup, integrations and reviewing logs to help pinpoint WHEN it happens may help with the process of elimination to locate the issue and fix it.  Disabling your Magmi integration briefly may be something to consider as well to determine if the table still is missing or not. Anyhow, hope this helps and here's some further reading on the flat table/indexing:

Resources:

- http://alanstorm.com/magento_flat_collection_chaos/
- [Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cpaneluser_magento.catalog_category_flat' doesn't exist'](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/base-table-or-view-not-found-1146-table-cpaneluser-magento-catalog-category-fl/45489#45489)
- [When should I use the category flat table option?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8082/when-should-i-use-the-category-flat-table-option?rq=1)
- [Permanent solution for the common indexing issue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3028/permanent-solution-for-the-common-indexing-issue/3081#3081)

Comment: No i have not any error while running indexing from CLI using this command `php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall`

Comment: There is not log but i can see error report on var/report folder

Comment: Whats the contents of some of the files in `var/report` they are just text files so you can view them easily to see exceptions.

Comment: This is a good suggestion +1: How are you normally re-indexing via the CLI? Do you receive any Exception or error messages when running it from the command line? php -f shell/indexer.php reindexall I found errors this way.